# Buffer a single line, don't dissolve overlapping areas of buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

Is it possible in ArcGIS to buffer ***one*** line and have the buffer ***not*** dissolve together the overlapping areas. Other questions here addressed dealing with overlapping areas of multiple features within the same feature class. But I'm curious about the *same feature*.

A buffer like what is drawn is what I'm looking for.

[image: overlapping buffer on same line example]

Comment: There would have to be some topological relationship for this to work, right?

Comment: You might try to split line at vertices, buffer, convert to line and delete unwanted segments. Output is going to be polyline, not polygon

Comment: It is a fundamental requirement of polygon topology that the polyline boundary cannot intersect itself at other than a point (and only under specific circumstances). You will find it exceedingly difficult to construct a polygon that meets your requirement, and it will be only slightly easier to construct a polyline from the pieces and parts of buffering each segment independently. Please do not add comments to your own post, especially issues which should be in the question proper.