# Avoid losing overlapping areas when buffering line with Python

Tags: python, geopandas, buffer, overlapping-features, linestring

`LineString` is the path of the transport on the field with attached equipment. Is it possible to use GeoPandas or third-party Python libraries to find overlapping areas when buffering a path line to a given equipment width?

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214003/buffer-a-single-line-dont-dissolve-overlapping-areas-of-buffer) is the most relevant in sense, but it has been over 6 years since the last edit.

The red section is an approximate overlap when buffering the white line.

[image]

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

points = [[0, 0], [0, 2], [0.5, 2.5], [1, 3], [1.5, 2.5], [2, 2], [2, 0]]

black = gpd.GeoSeries(LineString(points)).buffer(1.5, cap_style=1)
white = gpd.GeoSeries(LineString(points))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a bit rusty with GeoPandas but I believe this is the result you are looking for:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

points = [[0, 0], [0, 2], [0.5, 2.5], [1, 3], [1.5, 2.5], [2, 2], [2, 0]]

line = LineString(points)

# split line into individual segments
segments = []
for pt1,pt2 in zip(line.coords, line.coords[1:]):
    segments.append(LineString([pt1, pt2]))

# buffer each segment
buffers = [segment.buffer(1.5) for segment in segments]

# create GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(buffers, geometry=0).reset_index()

# get the intersection of each buffer successively 
overlayed = gpd.overlay(gdf.iloc[[0]], gdf.iloc[[1]])
for i in list(range(len(buffers)))[2:]:
    overlayed = gpd.overlay(gdf.iloc[[i]], overlayed)

overlayed.plot()
```

[image]

For reasons I do not know, the result ends up with a very large number of columns, but you can easily delete them.

Comment: Good spot, I changed a variable name I think but missed an instance. Thanks!